# Return specific part of string in each row SQL

Tags: t-sql

```
Column A

AAzzCC

A1zzC1

A2zzC2
```

How to select whole column but excluding "zz" part of the string from every single row? (I can't update or delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for MS Sql Server, using `REPLACE` function

```
SELECT REPLACE(Colum_A,'zz','') FROM Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE. Here is the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.120).aspx